# indent-region inconsistent with existing code that's indented more than python-indent-offset

Tags: init-file, python, indentation, prog-mode

Say I have an existing, simple block of code that uses an indent width of 4, as such

```
def incDictValue(d, k):

    if not k in d:
        d[k] = 1
    else:
        d[k] += 1

    return
```

and setup python-mode in my init.el file to use a 2 space indent offset, like such

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
    (setq tab-width 2)
    (setq python-indent-guess-indent-offset nil)
    (setq py-indent-offset 2)))
```

If I place the cursor on any line and hit TAB, the existing code is properly indented to match the indent offset of 2.

However, if I highlight the entire code block and `M-x indent-region`, only the second level indents are adjusted to 2. The first level indents (the 'if', 'else', and 'return' statements) are kept at 4.

```
def incDictValue(d, k):

    if not k in d:
      d[k] = 1
    else:
      d[k] += 1

    return
```

Why is this? This clearly isn't the desired result that one would want when applying indent-region. I would like indent-region to apply the indent settings of python-mode to the entire block of code, to all levels of indentation (much as if I hit TAB on each line sequentially)

Comment: I originally had it incorrectly as python-indent-offset. Fixed this to py-indent-offset, yet this indenting issue still exists

Comment: Are you sure? I only have `python-indent-offset` defined, not what you changed it to.  But I get the same behavior as you regardless: maybe send a bug report?

Comment: @NickD yeah, I was just going by the latest python-mode.el that I see on github. I'll file a bug there, as other prog modes don't exhibit this behavior

Comment: I believe there are *two* python modes: make sure that you do not confuse them. The one distributed with emacs is `python.el` originally by Fabian Gallina; the other one is `python-mode.el` originally by Barry Warsaw and maintained by Andreas Röhler.

Comment: @NickD ah, thanks for the heads up. Do you find one better than the other?